# Storing multiple foreach loop values into one array to be used in PHPExcel

Tags: php, arrays, phpexcel

I'm currently looping on an array with this structure:

```
Categories{
    CategoryName
    CategoryCode
    CategoryDescription

    Products{
        product_info{
            product_code
            product_type{
                CountNumber
                ProductDescription
            }
        }
        prices{
        "wholesale":"250",
        "retail":"400"
        }
    }   
}
```

I'm looping on the above array at each level, and I've declared an array so that I can put all my needed values into it

```
$priceResult = array();

foreach($prices->categories as $category){ 
    $categoryName = $category->category_name;
    $categoryCode = $category->category_code;
    $categoryDescription = $category->category_desc;

    foreach($category->products as $product){

        foreach($product->product_info as $info){
            $product_code = $info->product_code;
            foreach($info->product_type as $type){
                $CountNumber = $type->CountNumber;
                $ProductDescription = $type->ProductDescription;
            }
        }
        foreach ($product->prices as $price => $amount) {
            $price_amount = $amount;

        }
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is I don't know how to properly push into that new `$priceResult` array so that I can use PHPExcel to put it into a format with a subheader.

The format I would want from the above example would be something like this

```
    Test Category 1  |  123  |   Category for Testing
    ==================================================
    PRD123 |  12  |  Product for Testing  |  150.00
    PRD112 |  17  |  Product for Testing  |  250.00

    Test Category 2  |  321  |   New Category for Testing
    =====================================================
    PRD189 |  16  |  Product for Testing  |  450.00
    PRD139 |  34  |  Product for Testing  |  350.00
```

So basically I want to call PHPExcel on my $priceResult array in order to get that format where I can list my category info, and for each product within that category, I'd have a product row. Everything would be grouped by the category main header

```
    $build = Excel::create($name, function ($excel) use ($priceResult) {

    $excel->setTitle('Test Products');
```

UPDATE:

SO I'm thinking my desired resulting array would be something like:

```
CategoryCode : 123
CategoryName : TestCategory
CategoryDescription: For Testing
    Products{
        0{
            Product_code : 123,
            CountNumber : 12,
            ProductDescription: Test Product,
            price_amount : 150.00
        },
        1{
            Product_code : 112,
            CountNumber : 32,
            ProductDescription: Test Product 2,
            price_amount : 250.00
        }
    }
```

That way each category can be a header and all of its products can be rows for each category

Comment: Not entirely clear what your desired resulting array structure is, but you could collect all product prices into `$priceResult` array by replacing the line `$price_amount = $amount;` to `$priceResult[] = $amount`.

Comment: Sorry for any confusion with pricing verbiage, but basically all 7 of the variables in my nested loops I would like to put into one array. So I'm trying to say that for each parent level (categories) Iw ant all products within it so that I can create a header for category info and under each header have it's corresponding product/pricing

Comment: @marekful in other words, If I were to push everything to ```$priceResult[]``` then I would have 7 variables represented but I'm trying to get it into PHPExcel so that I can create subheaders based on it

Comment: You have to push arrays into the main array. Each sub-array would have 7 elements. The main array could be associative using category code as index.

Comment: Please update your post with the desired resulting array.

Comment: Ok I've updated with what I think should be my desired output if it makes sense @marekful

Comment: @marekful Does that desired output make sense?